# Parameterized Require

Tags: racket

I'm working on a project where I have a set of common tests, and a selection of various potential implementations of the system being tested. I would like to be able to parameterize the test module with the implementation.

Essentially, I have something like this:

```
(module foo racket 
   (define (dummy-function) 2))

(module bar racket 
   (define (dummy-function) 4))
```

And then want to test it with something that looks like the following

```
(module test racket
    (require [STUFF])
    (test-function (dummy-function) 4))
```

Ideally, I would be able to parameterize test with foo and bar, for example

```
(require (test foo))
```

But I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the quick and dirty answer here is that you want [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=dynamic-require#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29).

Given modules `foo` and `bar` above, you can do:

```
(module test racket
    (define dummy-function (if <condition>
                               (dynamic-require 'foo 'dummy-function)
                               (dynamic-require 'bar 'dummy-function)))
    (test-function (dummy-function) 4))
```

Note that if `foo` and `bar` are not installed globally, you probably want them  to be strings `"foo.rkt"` and `"bar.rkt"`.

A probably more robust solution is to use [units](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/units.html?q=units#%28tech._unit%29), but that would require more effort.